# Static Data Grid - 10K records with search, pagination, export options

Tags: javascript

Tested the following grids

1. Datatables
2. Angular UI grid
3. Slick Grid
4. Bootstrap

Observation:

- Datatables and Bootstrap grid is very slow
- Slick grid is not active as of now
- Angular UI grid doesn't support or have all export options

What is the fastest data grid which has the following features

1. search
2. pagination
3. html example
4. export options - csv, copy to clipboard, png, word, excel, csv, png, xml

Comment: you already have accepted solution in one of your previous similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45875010/3898339)

Comment: but now i am facing problem in having export options due to inactive or not available options..as far as the grid is concern it is good..

Comment: Example. 1. https://uploadfiles.io/16oj1 2. https://files.fm/u/ntg2brh4#_

Comment: Can you update your `Tested the following grids` list to include [links like this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links) to the actual libraries. It would add to the quality of the question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My current favorite table library is [Bootstrap-Table](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table)

[image: wenzhixin/bootstrap-table]

It has all the features you looking for and works quite well.

1. [HTML Example, Search, Pagination](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/index.html)
2. [Export Options](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#extensions/export.html)

To achieve decent loading times on 10k+ records you will most likely need to use [AJAX and/or Pagination](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#options/client-side-pagination.html).

Here is a snippet showing 5000 results working fine:

```html
<html>

<head>

  <!-- bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">  
  <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- bootstrap-table-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.18.3/bootstrap-table.min.css" integrity="sha512-5RNDl2gYvm6wpoVAU4J2+cMGZQeE2o4/AksK/bi355p/C31aRibC93EYxXczXq3ja2PJj60uifzcocu2Ca2FBg==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.18.3/bootstrap-table.min.js" integrity="sha512-Wm00XTqNHcGqQgiDlZVpK4QIhO2MmMJfzNJfh8wwbBC9BR0FtdJwPqDhEYy8jCfKEhWWZe/LDB6FwY7YE9QhMg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.18.3/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.min.js" integrity="sha512-cAMZL39BuY4jWHUkLWRS+TlHzd/riowdz6RNNVI6CdKRQw1p1rDn8n34lu6pricfL0i8YXeWQIDF5Xa/HBVLRg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- font-awesome -->  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/js/all.min.js" integrity="sha512-RXf+QSDCUQs5uwRKaDoXt55jygZZm2V++WUZduaU/Ui/9EGp3f/2KZVahFZBKGH0s774sd3HmrhUy+SgOFQLVQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  

  <!-- jquery -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <table data-toggle="table"
       data-search="true"
       data-show-refresh="true"
       data-show-toggle="true"
       data-show-columns="true"
       data-show-export="true"
       data-minimum-count-columns="2"
       data-show-pagination-switch="true"
       data-pagination="true"
       data-id-field="id"
       data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, ALL]"
       data-show-footer="false"
       data-side-pagination="client"
       data-url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-field="id">Id</th>
        <th data-field="title">Title</th>
        <th data-field="url">URL</th>
        <th data-field="thumbnailUrl">Thumbnail URL</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
</body>

</html>
```

So a few things are happening here that are improving performance:

1. Since the data is flowing more naturally to the library we get a nice "Loading ..." which makes users all warm and fussy on the inside. If not only because it is giving feedback to the user. Therefore we are willing to wait a few extra seconds.
2. We are switching from a HTML table with data in it to a JSON object.

> When using HTML for a data source the page has to fully render an overly verbose representation of the data (this blocks JavaScript form loading). Then the library loads and starts parsing this data (5,000 rows X 10 columns = 50,000 elements). Then the library has to apply its logic to the DOM. Depending on how the code is written this would mean processing all the results 3x.

OR

> When using JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) the HTML page is very light so it finishes rendering immediately. Also the data is in a native language to JavaScript and therefore it is read directly into a JavaScript object.  The library creates a object and binds it to the content of the table. Meaning that it takes 1 object to be added for the table to start rendering.

Essentially we are adding parallelism to the rendering of the results. So all 3 steps are still happening but in the former case each step has to wait for the next. Whereas in the latter case the steps are happening in parallel. And since we feel its done loading as soon as it renders 1 row it feels much faster.

Added exporting per your request but the actual library errors probably a limitation of the snippet tool.

---

For Bootstrap v4 start, we use Font Awesome as the default icons, so need to import [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/).

You can find the newest library from [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries)

Comment: This example is what i have used..However it hangs above 5,000 records..I have html with static data..but hanged for several seconds...If there is any solution to performance it would be great

Comment: Example. 1. https://uploadfiles.io/16oj1 2. https://files.fm/u/ntg2brh4#_

Comment: I have added a snippet showing a solution running fine with 5,000 results.

Comment: That's awesome..Could you please add the export options as well and see whether the performance is still quicker ??? between what is the trick you did to know out of curiosity...

Comment: Added an explanation. Added exporting but it seems to error on export probably a limitation of the snippet tool.

Comment: Excellent..Could you please consider any other way to add the export buttons or we need to raise a bug? if required, can u raise a bug as your explanations and wordings are awesome..Thanks a lot for your precious time..

Comment: also, could you please attach all the files to this or provide a link to download the files...i.e json, html files and other files required to run this ?

Comment: I do not think it is a bug as it is probably prevented by the snippet tool because it is invoking a file download which could be used maliciously (possible feature request to error gracefully). As for attaching the files the only thing needed to make this work is the HTML above. So I feel there is no need to share anything more.

Comment: The example http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/ has lots of features but seems it got removed..can you please add it again if it doesn't affect the performance..then the HTML will looks whole and awesome

Comment: It's for me as well as for any other's reference

Comment: Thanks for your kind understanding and patience on the questions and quick responses

Comment: for me the data is a static data and not dynamic..ie..the data will reside in the same folder where the HTML is

Comment: Added other features you requested to the table example. You can download the data from the [data-url](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos)

Comment: sorry to trouble you..with the fix, the export button takes the whole row..can u bring it in the left hand side with small button as previous one...that's the only thing got screwed up

Comment: Fixed the export drop down it did nothing and so i removed it. You should still see the last icon is the export button.

Comment: thanks for your time fjoe...can u add few lines on how to put static data or add an example after the dynamic data example with static data..as the original intention to have static data..

Comment: This is using static data. It is in the form of JSON. The file i used is set under the data-url property on the table. You would just change this to the location of your JSON data file.

Comment: referring just the file in the same folder won't work and it throws exception. jquery.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Test/photos.json?order=asc&offset=0&limit=10. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: instead of data url can we hard-code the json data directly..if yes, let me know so that we can do that

Comment: This is way outside of the scope of the original question now. Ask a new question and I help you with that.

Comment: created a new question as requested..pls check and answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45967357/how-to-add-json-data-instead-of-data-url-to-populate-the-grid/45969091#45969091

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153425/discussion-between-fjoe-and-kathir).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are able to use React but have you checked out https://react-table.js.org or https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table ?  They both seem to meet everything on your list, *except* for export.

Export into different formats is hard to do generically, so there are bunch of different projects on https://www.npmjs.com that specifically deal with exporting data into different formats.

Good luck!

Comment: could you pls help me with the exact example which has huge data grid with export options ?

Comment: Example. 1. https://uploadfiles.io/16oj1 2. https://files.fm/u/ntg2brh4#_

Answer (score 0):

10K data very large for a normal client. Doesn't matter which js component. DataTables BootStrap and etc's very slow because client ram is not enough for showing 10k data.

Comment: Is 8GB ram is not sufficient ? There should be a way to fix it